# inotify --fromfile directive

Tags: linux, security, inotify

I have a system fedora 15 with xfce window manager.

I installed an inotify util to play with.

I want to control, what happens with my files during my work process. 
There is a command which i use today for running inotify

```
inotifywait --fromfile ~/list.inotify
```

That command easy read a list of folders and files to read and to ignore. 
There is my list (list.inotify)

```
/home/alex

@/home/alex/Torrnets/
@/home/alex/.pulse-cookie
```

So it should read my home folder and ignore Torrents folder and .pulse-cookie file.

It ignores Torrents as well. But it won't ignore a .pulse-cookie file.

Any solution for this ? (please don't post a solution to use pattern based ignore, i want to work with a file list with absolute path's)

```
$man inotify
   @<file>
          When watching a directory tree recursively, exclude the specified file from being watched.  The file must be specified with a relative or absolute path according to whether a relative or absolute path is given for watched directories.  If a  specific
          path is explicitly both included and excluded, it will always be watched.

          Note: If you need to watch a directory or file whose name starts with @, give the absolute path.

   --fromfile <file>
          Read filenames to watch or exclude from a file, one filename per line.  If filenames begin with @ they are excluded as described above.  If <file> is `-', filenames are read from standard input.  Use this option if you need to watch too many files to
          pass in as command line arguments.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a `-e` argument, `inotifywait` will call `inotify_add_watch` with `IN_ALL_EVENTS`, which causes events to occur for files inside watched directories - note that [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html) says:

> When  monitoring  a directory, the events marked with an asterisk (*) above can occur for files in the directory, in which case
>   the name field in the returned inotify_event structure identifies the name of the file within the directory.

If you have a look at the [inotifywait code in question](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/blob/master/libinotifytools/src/inotifytools.c#L1284), you'll see that it only watches (and checks the exclude list against) directories. It would perhaps be a bit more user  friendly if you were warned when specifying an exclusion that is not a directory or one that is never used, but that's the way it currently it is.